# Border cell rendering issue in IE 11 and Edge while zooming

Tags: html, css, border

The code:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  zoom: 1;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  zoom: 1;
}
.cell1 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FBFBFB 50%, #c7d41a 50%);
}
.cell2 {
  background-color: #c7d41a;
  zoom: 1;
}
.cell3 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #c7d41a 50%, #FBFBFB 50%);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell1">1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell2">2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell3">3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When zoom is 100%, everything is shown fine.
When zooming in > 100%, IE 11 and Edge creates bright border within the cells.

[image]

Does someone know a workaround to eliminate these borders?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvgckd8w/

Comment: Each browser does the zooming as they see fit. The point of zooming is to trade pixel perfect details for either readability or a birds-eye-view of the page.

Comment: Ehm, the fiddle doesn't have the same source as you have in your question.

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvgckd8w/2/